# to parse php into html using htaccess in latest godaddy server configuration

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web, web-hosting

I am parsing php into html using .htaccess in go-daddy server which was bought in 2014 and I am using this code:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .html
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .html
```

I tried above code in my new server but its not working. It's possible that go-daddy changed configuration.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! To attract good answers I would recommend you to edit your question with more details. Explain how it's not working - what is it doing, and what would you want it to do? Also read ["How do I ask a good question"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "go-daddy changed configuration" - this is quite possible. You should check with your host what the correct configuration should be.